# NewRelic with Prestashop Ecommerce Site

Tags: php, prestashop, vps, newrelic, agent

I have a Prestashop Site running on a Virtual Private Server (VPS)
in which I have correctly installed PHP New Relic Agent.

The agent is working fine and sending data to rpm.newrelic.

However, i have many web apps running on my VPS, under public_html/*

I want to discriminate on New Relic Dashboard the metrics for one particular site. Now is just saying 'PHP Application' and displaying data for all the server usage, including even phpmyadmin!

I know that I have to set (through New Relic PHP API) the following:

```
if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
  newrelic_set_appname($name);
}
```

But where shall i put this snippet of code, inside a Prestashop ecommerce instalation?

Is there another way to do this, for each app that I have on my VPS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to add this lines at the file: `/config/config.inc.php`?
This file uses only at the Prestashop, so other applications should not be able to influence to newrelic stats.

Regards, Alex

Comment: But is this the better place to put it?

Comment: We used this place on one of the projects and all worked perfect.